# How to modify common mongodb query to async with try and catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

This is my code with written with express js
**this query works but I think that using async is more reliable than this**

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/nodejs_crud";
const db_n = "nodejs_crud"

const client = new MongoClient(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    // this is myquery code with right result 
 
    client.connect((err) => {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        const db = client.db(db_n)
        db.collection("list").find({}).toArray((err, result) => {
            if(err) throw res.send({ status: "Error when react data", bool: false}).status(450);
            res.send(result).status(200);
        })
    })    

});
```

Comment: @ChrisG In the future please use doubtful wording and link to the help center when recommending Code Review. Take, "This may be on-topic on Code Review. Please check [if it is on-topic](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to post a good question](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting there."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, not exactly the same as yours, but will give you the idea on how to use async/await with try/catch

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/nodejs_crud";
const db_n = "nodejs_crud"

const client = new MongoClient(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    
    // Connect client if it's not connected
    if(!client.isConnected()) {
        await client.connect();

        // you can also catch connection error
        try {
            await client.connect();
        catch(err) {
            return res.status(500).send();
        }
    }

    const db = client.db(db_n);

    try {
        // Run queries
        const result = db.collection("list").find({});
        res.json(await result.toArray());
    } catch (err) {
        // Catch any error
        console.log(err.message);
        res.status(450).send();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but try something along the lines of:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/nodejs_crud";
const db_n = "nodejs_crud"

let client;

const getDb = async () => {
  // If we don't have a client, create one.
  if (!client) client = new MongoClient(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true });
  // If we are not connected, then connect.
  if (!client.connected()) await client.connect();
  // Get our database
  return client.db(db_n);
}

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const db = await getDb();
    const results = await db.collection("list").find({}).toArray();
    res.send(result).status(200);
  } catch (err) {
    res.send({ status: "Error when react data", bool: false}).status(450);
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't see where OP is looping over the results?

Comment: You're right, toArray is not forEach... i've misread it. He returns the full array.